# How to use proximity sensor to manage screen light :Android

Tags: android, proximitysensor

In my project I need to use proximity sensor to manage screen light.

From last 3 days I'm trying to do the same thing. But still I din't got success.

My half code is working fine. Am able to off the screen light using proximity sensor. but screen light not getting on. When I'm covering the sensor with my hand, screen light is getting off. but light not getting on after removing my hand from sensor.

My code is:

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event)
{
    if(event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY)
    {
        switch (lastSensorPosition)
        {
        //case 1 will turn on screen light
        case 1:
            lastSensorPosition = 2;
            WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = getWindow().getAttributes();
            lp.screenBrightness = WindowManager.LayoutParams.BRIGHTNESS_OVERRIDE_FULL;
            getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
            break;



        //case 2 will turn off screen light
        case 2:
            lastSensorPosition = 1;
            WindowManager.LayoutParams lp1 = getWindow().getAttributes();
            lp1.screenBrightness = WindowManager.LayoutParams.BRIGHTNESS_OVERRIDE_OFF;
            getWindow().setAttributes(lp1);
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm expecting a great help from you guys...

Answer (score 0):

```
private SensorManager mSensorManager;
private Sensor mSensor;
...
mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
mSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY);   


 public class SensorActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {
      private SensorManager mSensorManager;
      private Sensor mProximity;

      @Override
      public final void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Get an instance of the sensor service, and use that to get an instance of
        // a particular sensor.
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mProximity = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY);
      }

      @Override
      public final void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        // Do something here if sensor accuracy changes.
      }

      @Override
      public final void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        float distance = event.values[0];
        // Do something with this sensor data.
      }

      @Override
      protected void onResume() {
        // Register a listener for the sensor.
        super.onResume();
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mProximity, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
      }

      @Override
      protected void onPause() {
        // Be sure to unregister the sensor when the activity pauses.
        super.onPause();
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
      }
    }
```

Comment: if you need to turn the screen dark and not touchable ( to avoid mistaken click with your face ) , you can ad the fellowing code : 
` WindowManager.LayoutParams params = this.getWindow().getAttributes();
  if (event.values[0] == 0) {
 params.screenBrightness = 0f;
  this.getWindow().setAttributes(params);
 getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
  } else {
    params.screenBrightness = -1.0f;
this.getWindow().setAttributes(params);getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
}`

Answer (score 0):

Some proximity sensors return binary values that represent "near" or "far." In this case, the sensor usually reports its maximum range value in the far state and a lesser value in the near state. Typically, the far value is a value > 5 cm, but this can vary from sensor to sensor. You can determine a sensor's maximum range by using the getMaximumRange() method.